# If $(X,\| \|)$ be a Normed Linear Space.. Show that if any vector subspace $Y$ of $X$ is open, then $Y=X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,\| \|)$ be a Normed Linear Space, Show that if any vector subspace $Y$ of $X$ is open, then $Y=X$

**Attempt:** Subspace $Y$ of $X$ is open, $=> \exists ~~r >0 ~~\forall~~ y \in Y$ s.t $ B(y,r) \subset Y$ where $B(y,r)$ represents the open ball in $Y$ with centre $y$ and radius $r$.

Since, $B(y,r) \subset Y => \exists ~ u \in Y ~\& ~ \exists~ r>0$ s.t :

$B(y,r) = \{ u \in Y ~~|~~ d(u,y) <r \}$ where $d$ is the associated metric.

$B(y,r) = \{ u \in Y ~~|~~ \|u-y\| <r \}$ where $y \in Y ~~............(1)$

$Y$ is a subspace of $X$ . $=> \forall ~~u,y \in Y, ~ u+y \in Y ~~..........(2) $

and $\alpha ~y \in  Y~ \forall ~y \in Y ~~~  ...................(3) $

How do I proceed next? Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: If $Y$ is open, then for each $y\in Y$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $y+v\in Y$ for all $\left\|v\right\|<\epsilon$ (this is just a reformulation of the definition of "open").

Can you apply this to a suitable $y\in Y$? You will need to use the fact that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ - e.g., that $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ . $=> \forall ~~u,y \in Y, ~ u+y \in Y ~~  $ 

and $\alpha ~y \in  Y~ \forall ~y \in Y $

I need to apply this to a suitable $y$ now?

Comment: Dear @VHP, apply it to $y=0$. What do you get when you combine this with the fact that $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Since $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication $k~ 0_e = 0_e$ ( e represents the identity vector ) 

$B(0,r) = \{ u \in Y ~~|~~ \|u \| <r \}$

Comment: So ultimately, we need to prove that any $x \in X$ satisfies that : When  $\|x \| <r,~~ then ~~x \in U  $ ?

Comment: Dear @VHP, no, what I meant is that if you apply this to $y=0$, then you can conclude that some $\epsilon$-ball about the $0$ vector is contained in $Y$. Now use the fact that $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: $B(0, \epsilon) = \{y \in Y ~~|~~\|y\| < \epsilon\}$

Now, if $y \in Y ~ ,ky \in ~Y$, for any scalar $k$?

Comment: @VHP $B(0,\epsilon)=\{x\in X: \left\|x\right\| < \epsilon\}\subseteq Y$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Any vector in $X$ can be scaled to have norm $<\epsilon$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that helps. That means, any member $x$ of $X$ can satisfy the condition for the open ball in $Y$ which means $Y=X$.
Correct?

Comment: @VHP I'm not sure I would write it in that way. Essentially, the point is that if $x\in X$, then scaling $x$ by $\frac{\epsilon}{2\left\|x\right\|}$ will yield a vector in $B(0,\epsilon)$, which must hence be in $Y$. Now scale by the reciprocal of the previous scale factor (combining with the fact that $Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication) to conclude that $x\in Y$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: yes, but I think I didn't show containment in the other direction as well.

Comment: Dear @VHP, great! Thanks for accepting my answer. Please let me know if you would like to discuss this (or something else) further.

Answer (score 3):

Contraposition works best here. Show that if $X\neq Y$, $Y$ is not open. To do this, construct a sequence in $X\setminus Y$converging to $0$. Note that if $x\in X\setminus Y, \lambda x\in X\setminus Y$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$.

**Edit:** To show that $Y$ is not open, show that $B_{\epsilon}(0)\not\subset Y$ for all $\epsilon>0$. So given $\epsilon>0$, you must find $x\in X\setminus Y$ such that $\|x\|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I am afraid i haven't reached the chapter on convergence in a metric space, but I am trying to understand what you said.

Also, is it true that $\bigcup _{n \in N} B(0,nr) = X?$

Comment: @VHP Yes, for fixed $r$ that is correct. I've edited for clarification.